# Particle effect showing only on one side of mirrored object

Tags: modeling, particles, hair, effects

I'm trying to create a fur particle effect on sonic the hedgehog, and I'm using weight paints to keep it in the areas I want.

Problem: I can only get the hair effect to show up on certain random areas on model, and only on one side.

I'm using a mirror effect to keep model symmetrical, but hair only shows on one side of the mirror.

I'm new used Blender, so I don't know what all the settings for the particle effects do.

Whats going on and how do I fix it?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3nnI6YdPSHcN19NZTdzRlk2b3c/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer because it probably has nothing to do with this problem at all. I can't figure out what it is though. I'll share on Twitter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have the mirror modifier be on top of the particle system.

[image]

Use the arrows top and down arrows on the right of the modifiers to re arrange the modifier stack.

[image]

Then in the particle system enable **Use Modifier Stack**

[image]

Comment: Aahh yes, there it is. I couldn't find it either. It's also helpful for me.