# Mirror applied to object with displacement does not mesh

Tags: mirror, displacement

I have a plane with displacement to make waves. It has particles for grass. I added it to a collection instance. I mirrored it. After mirroring, the grass only show on the original. If I apply the mirror the grass shows on the other as well.

If I create a new collection instance the displacement meshes with the rest fo the model, but once the mirror is applied, the displacement on all the planes don't match up anymore. There's gaps between the planes.

I thought using collection instances might be more efficient, but maybe I should just make mirrors and duplicate?

[image: Mirrored image]

[image: Mirror applied]

Comment: The order of the modifiers on the stack matters, mirror should be over the particle modifiers. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88395/particle-effect-showing-only-on-one-side-of-mirrored-object

Comment: Omg yes. That along with the use modifier stack setting did it. Thank you!

Comment: Please write a full answer that describes how you solved your issue. Other users with a similar problem will appreciate it.

Comment: I put the mirror modifier over the particle modifier and checked off use modifier stack in the emissions tab of the particle system

Comment: Please write the answer on the answers section (not as a comment) and accept your own answer. Read: [can I answer my own question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) Other users with a similar question can learn from your experience.