# Is there a faster way for me to create this hair?

Tags: modeling

I am currently trying to model curly hair on this model.  To simulate it I have been placing and duplicating these brown shapes you see here, but its very slow and time consuming.  Is there a quicker way to do this?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use particles > *Hair*. Create a sphere that will be your particle hair. In *Weight Paint* mode, paint the vertex group where you want the particles to appear:

[image]

In the *Particle System* panel, create a new particle system > *Hair*, under *Render* choose the sphere and give it a bit bit of *Scale Randomness*. Under *Vertex Groups* select the vertex group that you've created as *Density* and *Length*:

[image]

If you want to make the instances real, open the *Modifier* panel and click on *Make Instances Real*:

[image]

Comment: thank u for ur answer!  The only problem I now have is the hair is only populating on one side--could this be an issue with the mirror modifier?

Comment: because the issue I have when I get rid of the mirror modifier is it fills in unevenly then

Comment: You can keep the Mirror modifier if you want, check the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88395/particle-effect-showing-only-on-one-side-of-mirrored-object  Basically put the Mirror modifier above the Particle System and in the Particle System panel enable the Emission > Source > Use Modifier Stack option

Comment: Thanks--that worked for me being able to keep the mirror modifier on, but its still filling it in uneven on both sides.  I have an image here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WlXuxr3TVYgwCCH3vzDAXteP6bMRqnL3/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XO-Zr-O9FGa36IqNZlSpu9emeiokpdPS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: whoops the first one is the wrong screenshot lol

Comment: yes the particles are not symmetrical if this is what you mean, i'm not sure how you could achieve that